# JGit to Github Blob Object SHA1 Consistency

Tags: java, git, github, jgit

I am trying to generate a Github URL to the specific blob in a commit using JGit. I'm not sure whether the object IDs generated by JGit's [AnyObjectId.getName()](http://download.eclipse.org/jgit/docs/jgit-2.0.0.201206130900-r/apidocs/org/eclipse/jgit/lib/AnyObjectId.html#getName()) are the same SHA1 Hashes used to identify objects in GitHub. Logically it would make sense that they are. However, they don't seem to be aligned.

Here's my code:

```
Git gitInstance = Util.getGitInstance(); // get the git instance instantiated earlier
String blobTarget = "file.txt";
RevCommit thisCommit = Util.getTargetCommit(); // get the commit I'm looking for
TreeWalk treeWalk = new TreeWalk(gitInstance.getRepository());
treeWalk.addTree(thisCommit.getTree());
treeWalk.setRecursive(true);

while( treeWalk.next() ) {
    String blobSHA1 = treeWalk.getObjectId(0).getName(); // This value does not match GitHub's SHA1 for the blob
    if( blobTarget.equals(treeWalk.getPathString()) {
        String gitHubURL = "https://github.com/myUser/myRepo/commit/" + 
                                            thisCommit.getName() + "#diff-" +  blobSHA1);
        System.out.println(gitHubURL);
    }
}
```

Expected:

```
https://github.com/myUser/myRepo/commit/060ebb2f784764b704ddf92d883c61fd71798eb9#diff-ecdc430280760f99f1dae6953ca4ce00
```

Actual:

```
https://github.com/myUser/myRepo/commit/060ebb2f784764b704ddf92d883c61fd71798eb9#diff-e220724cbf8a5229183f199c11f8a3b28b5f6145
```

The Actual link has an incorrect blob SHA1, so the generated URL links to the correct commit but doesn't link to any valid blob. I believe that `treeWalk.getObjectId(0)` is a reference to the same blob that is available on GitHub, as reading that ID's object with an ObjectLoader produces the identical content of the blob on GitHub.

Comment: `treeWalk.next()` starts the iterator on the first entry in the tree of the given commit. If you are looking for a specific entry (i.e. file) you need to filter for the entry's name. For example by using `TreeWalk.forPath(repo, path, tree) ` (returns a `treeWalk` positioned on the requested entry.

Comment: @RüdigerHerrmann Sorry, that part of my code got lost when I compiled the minimum code required for this example. I'll update the code in the question.